# Is Warren Buffett the "only ... man in history [who] has invested billions of dollars of other people’s money successfully over the long run"?

Tags: finance

In ["$1 billion stakes on the menu"](http://www.economist.com/news/business/21699139-meaning-two-odd-and-connected-investments-1-billion-stakes-menu), *The Economist* (2016-05-21 print edition) writes:

> only one man in history has invested billions of dollars of other people’s money successfully over the long run: Warren Buffett.

Is this claim plausible?

Comment: Most fund managers don't even beat the market average. Whether Buffet is the *only* exception or one of a small elite is open to question. He is clearly the only one in the top 10 billionaire list who made his wealth this way.

Comment: Whoever answers this should take the words 'only' AND 'billions' from the quote. Those words might make the claim true. as @matt_black said, definitely top 10, but might be the only one with billions to the claim.